# Can one show a dialog in superclass?

Tags: android

I have a subclass of ListActivity that is reused throughout my project, subclassed again so that each reports to a different ActivityGroup. This is working beautifully until I try to present a dialog in the superclass (as this behaviour should be exhibited by each subclass), and I get the following error:

```
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31514): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Now, I think this is due to the context that is being fed into the AlertDialog.Builder. I am using standard sample code from [Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Any ideas appreciated.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: try **this.getApplicationContext()**

Comment: Instead presenting the dialog containing items this way, I decided to create a new activity which could then present it's own dialog box no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the activity is part of an ActivityGroup. You cannot open a dialog with a context of the current activity in the ActivityGroup, instead provide the context of the ActivityGroup itself.

In the Activity from which you want to present the dialog:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivityGroup.group);
```

In the ActivityGroup subclass, MyActivityGroup, define your static reference:

```
public static MediaMenuGroup group;
```

then

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
group = this;

...
```